# Spatial Lag returns unexpected result

Tags: python, autocorrelation, model, spatial

I am getting an unexplainable result as my spatial lag.
I read the data as follows

```
import geopandas as gp
from pysal.lib import weights
import pysal as ps

data = gp.read_file('...')
data.set_index('someIndex')
# create the spatial weights matrix
w = weights.contiguity.Rook.from_dataframe(data)
# calculate the spatial lag
data['spatial_lag'] = weights.spatial_lag.lag_spatial(w, data['count'])
```

So far, so good. Now I want to double check.

```
data.loc[324, ['name', 'count', 'spatial_lag']]
```

Which returns

```
name               FooBar
count              11256.0
spatial_lag        5170.0
```

As far as I understand, the spatial lag is the `mean` of the `count` of the neighbouring geometries (as defined by the spatial weight matrix `w`) from `324`. So I should be able to calculate/reconstruct the spatial lag of `FooBar` from the `mean()` of the `count` of the neighbouring geometries

```
print(data.loc[w.neighbors[324], 'count'].mean())
```

> 574.4444444444445

Well this is unexpected. It should be `5170.0`, right?
Looking at the neighbouring values

```
print(data.loc[w.neighbors[324], ['name', 'count', 'spatial_lag']])
```

Which is

```
                    name           count  spatial_lag
328              A                 556.0      12332.0
329              B                 659.0      12858.0
330              C                 567.0      13122.0
332              D                 424.0      14237.0
333              E                 573.0      12561.0
334              F                 657.0      13698.0
336              G                 504.0      12825.0
338              H                 652.0      14175.0
341              I                 578.0      13068.0
```

So, why is the spatial lag for `324` calculated as `5170.0` and not `574.4444444444445`?

Comment: I am pretty sure `w = weights.contiguity.Rook.from_dataframe(data)` does not default to creating the spatial weight matrix w as row normalized, [maybe something like this](http://darribas.org/gds_scipy16/ipynb_md/03_spatial_weights.html) after `w.transform = 'r'`, and then do the spatial lag (or keep as is, do a spatial lag of a constant 1 field, and divide the sum by the number of neighbors. IMO this should be transferred to the GIS site.